# Applying feFlood filter to <tspan> not working as expected

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to apply a background color to only one word in a `text` element using the `feFlood` filter.

What's happening though is that the flood is filling all of the parent element and even hiding some of the text.

**DEFS**

```
<filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="colorMe">
    <feFlood flood-color="red"/>
    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
```

**STYLE**

```
.colorMe {
        filter: url(#colorMe);
        fill: #ccc;
    }
text{
    fill: #fff;
    font: 40px Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

As I didn't include `x,y,width,height` to flood I presumed it would fill just the `tspan` - It's difficult to include these as the class is added dynamically on `tspan` elements of various size

Is there a way to add a background color to just one word?

Code snippet below and [here's a fiddle too](https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/67nen0fs/2/)

**ALL CODE**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="450" height="40" viewBox="0 0 450 40"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
 <defs>
   <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="colorMe">
        <feFlood flood-color="red"/>
        <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </filter>
 </defs>
  <style>
  .colorMe {
  filter: url(#colorMe);
  fill: #ccc;
 }
text{
    fill: #fff;
    font: 40px Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
 </style>
    <text x="15" y="30">You are 
     <tspan class="colorMe">not</tspan> 
     me
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: `filters` are not friendly to `tspan` even in 2016, need two `text` elements, however from experience sometimes the colored `text` looks slightly misaligned, depending on browser and fonts.

Comment: I've come to learn that `<tspan>`s are basically second-class citizens, and I avoid them whenever possible. Even in 2022, things like `transform`, `filters`, etc on them have problems in certain browsers. If you're having cross-compatibility problems and you're using tspans, that's probably the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems browsers haven't agreed on whether filters are valid on `<tspan>` or not.

The spec says that filter applies to "container elements (except mask) and graphics elements".  Technically `<tspan>` is in neither of these categories.

The Firefox developers have decided that filter is not valid on tspans (see [this bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=917766)).

Your test works fine in IE.

And it seems as if Chrome thinks it should work - it's just bugged at the moment.  I've filed a [bug report in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=603157) on your behalf.